# Mysql Two tables mixed data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mixed

I have two tables:

table1:

```
ID| Name
1 | firstname1
2 | firstname2
3 | firstname3
```

table2:

```
ID| Name
1 | lastname1
2 | lastname2
3 | lastname3
```

And i want insert combination table1 and table2 to table3 example:
table3:

```
ID| Fullname
1 | firstname1-lastname1
2 | firstname1-lastname2
3 | firstname1-lastname3
4 | firstname2-lastname1
5 | firstname2-lastname2
6 | firstname2-lastname3
7 | firstname3-lastname1
8 | firstname3-lastname2
9 | firstname3-lastname3
```

A try in php (pdo) but is very slow... i must create 10 000 000 records (after combination)

my php:

```
<?php
//get firstnames, get lastnames before and...
foreach ($firstnames as $firstname) {
    foreach ($lastnames as $lastname) {
        $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `table3` (`fullname`) VALUES(?)")->execute([$firstname['name'] . '-' . $lastname['name']]);
    }
}
```

Soo, how i can create a query that mix data?

Thans

Comment: I'm confused. Is your question about slowly inserting data or on joining two tables?

Comment: Just to let you know, I hate spammers.

Comment: use left join and union with inner join query to get your desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below SQL to insert data in table3

```
  INSERT INTO table3(fullname ) SELECT concat( table1.name,'-',table2.name ) FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2;
```

Comment: It won't make the desired result

Comment: I think Arkadiusz is looking for a cartesian join, not an inner join.

Comment: Sorry guys ... I updated the SQL .. Thanks for the update

Comment: That still won't work, the IDs won't be right (you'll get duplicates)

To solve it you could insert the joined value and set the table id's to auto-increment.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work, if you set the third's table id to auto-increment.

However, I'm not that familiar with mySQL's dialect, so this may or may not be right

```
INSERT INTO table3 (fullname) 
VALUES( 
    SELECT table1.id, 
           concat( table1.name,'-',table2.name) 
    FROM table1 
    CROSS JOIN table2
)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you wanna just retrieve the data from different tables and use it in php you can use a query like this.
You should give your columns different names in each table , that's always a helpful thing to do.

```
$query = "SELECT
    table1.*,
    table2.*
    FROM
    table1, table2
    WHERE
   table1.id=table2.id
    ";
```

$row_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);